# How to use the logical 'OR' operator with "should be" in scala?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I was trying to use the "should be" function along with the logical "OR" operator as follows (for example) :

```
 def String(x :Integer) :Integer ={
       /*----------------
      -----------------*/
      return value;
 }

 String.value.size should be (8) || String.value.size should be (0) /*that is anything other than the value 8 or 0 should cause a false and the program should start execution */
```

But I get an error saying  "value || is not a member of org.scalatest.matchers.Matcher[Any]"

Can somebody help me here. Thank you in advance..

Comment: You should not do it! Your test needs to be deterministic

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like `String.value.size should be (8)` returns an instance of `org.scalatest.matchers.Matcher` which does not have a member `||`. According to [this](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.0/org/scalatest/matchers/ShouldMatchers.html) you should use `or` for disjunction e.g.

```
String.value.size should (be (8) or be (0))
```